# How do I include a module in a namespaced class?

Tags: ruby

I am having trouble including a module in a namespaced class. The example below throws the error `uninitialized constant Bar::Foo::Baz (NameError)`. What basic piece of Ruby knowledge am I missing here?

```
module Foo
  module Baz
    def hello
      puts 'hello'
    end
  end
end

module Bar
  class Foo
    include Foo::Baz
  end
end

foo = Bar::Foo.new
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `::` to force the lookup to the top level only:

```
module Bar
  class Foo
    include ::Foo::Baz
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`include ::Foo::Baz`